# Helicon ISAPI redirect or URLRewrite.net Managed Code redirect?

Tags: .net-2.0, httpmodule, isapi-redirect

We have a web application that currently uses [URLRewrite.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html), and I'm thinking about pulling it out to use [Helicon's ISAPI rewrite 3.0.](http://www.helicontech.com/forum/forum10-ISAPI_Rewrite_30.html).
We have about 100 redirect rules of varying complexity and both redirect solutions can do the job, but I'm looking to free up managed code resources for our site.  I'm thinking of these links in particular: [Tess's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/23/net-memory-leak-case-study-the-event-handlers-that-made-the-memory-baloon.aspx) and [Kurt's blog](http://kurtschindler.net/blog/post/UrlRewritingNet-performance-issues).

Does any one have any experience with either product? What did you think?